# How to enable scroll for specific portion of a HTML page

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am using Scss for styling the page and need to set scroll for specific parts of a HTML page.

[image]

when a user doing a scroll I need to keep the Categories(left) & Cart (Right) area to be strick in their position. But the center part needs to be scroll till the filtered items are reaching the top (bottom of the breadcrumb). If the user scroll further the filtered items will scroll underneath the filter and search bar section.

Can Anyone help me to fix it.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
 

  <div class="row pt-4 pr-0">

    <div class="col-sm-12 px-4 pt-2">
      <app-gropcard-breadcrumb></app-gropcard-breadcrumb>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <mat-card class="col-sm-12 p-0 mat-elevation-z10" style="background-color: #0084FF;color: white;">
            <mat-card-header class="d-flex justify-content-center p-2">
              <mat-card-title class="mb-0">Categories</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
              
              <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="tree mt-3 pl-3                                                                        ">
                <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
                <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
                  <li class="mat-tree-node">
                    <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
                    <button class="TreeButton" mat-icon-button disabled></button>
                    <span (click)="Category(node)">{{node.name}}</span>
                  </li>
                </mat-tree-node>
                <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
                <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
                  <li>
                    <div class="mat-tree-node" [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
                      <button class="TreeButton" mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle 
                              [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                          {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                        </mat-icon>
                      </button>
                      <span matTreeNodeToggle (click)="Category(node)">{{node.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="pl-2" [class.tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
                      <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </mat-nested-tree-node>
              </mat-tree>
             
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 containerbackground">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0  d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img class="w-100 banner"
              [src]="mListedPartyBanner">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <h5 class="mt-4 mb-2">Filtered Items</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-5 search pt-4" fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="false">
                <form class="search"  >
                <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                  <input type="text" #myInput matInput placeholder="Search" maxlength="50" (input)="Search(myInput.value)"  autocomplete='null' [formControl]="myControl">
                  
                  <button matTooltip="Search" matSuffix mat-icon-button>
                    <mat-icon>
                      search
                    </mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </mat-form-field>
                </form>
           </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4  d-flex justify-content-end">
                <div class="View mt-4 mb-2 mr-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <button matTooltip="Filter"[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon>filter_list</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button  (click)="sortBy(data?.id)" mat-menu-item *ngFor="let data of sortList" [value]="data?.id">
                      <span>{{data?.value}}</span>
                    </button>
                  </mat-menu>

                    <button [ngClass]="{'ActiveButton': displayMode === 1}" (click)="onDisplayModeChange(1)"
                      matTooltip="List view" mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon>view_headline</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button [ngClass]="{'ActiveButton': displayMode === 2}" (click)="onDisplayModeChange(2)"
                      matTooltip="Grid view" mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon>view_module</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>

          <div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf='displayMode==1'>
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-sm-6 p-2 " *ngFor="let prod of ListedPartyItems; let ind = index">
                <mat-card class="py-1" matRipple>
                  <div class="corner-ribbon top-right sticky blue shadow" *ngIf='prod?.PROMO_PRICE'>
                    {{((prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE-prod?.PROMO_PRICE)/prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE)*100 | number: '1.0-0'}}% Off</div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="ImageDiv">
                      <img class="w-100 Img p-1" [src]="prod['IMAGE_PATH_1']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row NameDiv d-flex ProductData justify-content-center">
                      <div class="Name mt-2">
                        <span>{{prod?.ITEM_DESCRIPTION}}</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Price mt-2">
                        <span class="ProductPrice">{{prod?.PROMO_PRICE ? (prod?.PROMO_PRICE | number:'.1-2') :
                          (prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE | number:'.1-2')}}<span class="pl-1"
                            [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></span>
                        <span class="PromotionPrice mt-1 pl-1" *ngIf='prod?.PROMO_PRICE'>{{prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE |
                          number:'.1-2'}}<span class="pl-1" [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">

                          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2  w-100">
                            <button type="button" (click)="Decrement( ind)" class="btnStyles">–</button>
                            <input type="text" readonly class="quantityBox" [(ngModel)]="prod.qty">
                            <button type="button" (click)="Increment(ind)" class="btnStyles">+</button>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-sm-12 mt-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <button (click)="AddToCart(prod?.PRODUCT_CODE,prod?.UOM,prod?.qty, ind)"
                                  class="col-sm-12 ProductButton " mat-raised-button>
                                  <mat-icon class="iconSize Cursor">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <button (click)="SelectedProduct(prod?.PRODUCT_CODE)" class="col-sm-12 ProductButton"
                                  mat-raised-button>More</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </mat-card>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf='displayMode==2'>

            <div class="row">
              <div *ngIf="IsItemFound" style="display:block;margin:auto;">
                <img src="../../../../assets/oops.png" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 p-2" *ngFor="let prod of ListedPartyItems; let ind = index">
                <mat-card matRipple class="p-0 ">
                  <div class="corner-ribbon top-right sticky blue shadow" *ngIf='prod?.PROMO_PRICE'>
                    {{((prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE-prod?.PROMO_PRICE)/prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE)*100 | number: '1.0-0'}}% Off</div>
                  <img class="d-block w-100 Img p-1" [src]="prod['IMAGE_PATH_1']">
                  <div class="w-100 d-flex ProductData justify-content-center">{{prod?.ITEM_DESCRIPTION}}</div>

                  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <span class="ProductPrice">{{prod?.PROMO_PRICE ? (prod?.PROMO_PRICE | number:'.1-2') :
                      (prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE | number:'.1-2')}}<span class="pl-1"
                        [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></span>
                    <span class="PromotionPrice mt-1 pl-1" *ngIf='prod?.PROMO_PRICE'>{{prod?.PRODUCT_PRICE |
                      number:'.1-2'}}<span class="pl-1" [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2">
                    <button type="button" (click)="Decrement( ind)" class="btnStyles">–</button>
                    <input type="text" readonly class="quantityBox" [(ngModel)]="prod.qty">
                    <button type="button" (click)="Increment(ind)" class="btnStyles">+</button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="w-100 mt-2">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="w-50 ">
                        <button (click)="AddToCart(prod?.PRODUCT_CODE,prod?.UOM,prod?.qty, ind)"
                          class="col-sm-12 ProductButton p-0" mat-raised-button>Add To Cart</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="w-50">
                        <button (click)="SelectedProduct(prod?.PRODUCT_CODE)" class="col-sm-12 ProductButton p-0"
                          mat-raised-button>More</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </mat-card>
              </div>
            </div>


















          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <mat-card class="col-sm-12 p-0 mat-elevation-z10 YourCartheight">
            <mat-card-header class="d-flex justify-content-center p-2"  style="background-color: #0084FF;color: white;">
              <mat-card-title class="mb-0">Your Cart</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
              
              <div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="!IsMyCartHasItems">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center mt-4">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 emptycart p-1" src="../../../../../assets/cart.png" alt="No Data">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 pb-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <span>There are no items in your cart.</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             
              <div class="col-sm-12 p-2"  *ngIf="IsMyCartHasItems">
                <div class="row" *ngFor="let prod of MyCart; let i = index">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 p-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 p-2">
                      <span style="font-size: 12px;">{{prod.ITEM_DESC}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 p-2  mt-2">
                      <button type="button" (click)="Decrementsub(prod?.ITEM_CODE,prod?.ITEM_PACK_SIZE,prod?.TOTAL_QTY,i)" class="cartBtn">–</button>
                      <input type="text" readonly class="quantityBox1" [value]="prod.TOTAL_QTY">
                      <button type="button" (click)="Incrementsub(prod?.ITEM_CODE,prod?.ITEM_PACK_SIZE,prod?.TOTAL_QTY,i)" class="cartBtn">+</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-2 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 p-2  mt-2">
                      <span>{{prod?.TOTAL_AMT | number}} <span class="pl-1 Price"
                        [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-2 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 p-1">
                      <button matTooltip="Remove"
                      (click)="RemoveCartProduct(prod?.ITEM_CODE,prod?.ITEM_PACK_SIZE)" mat-icon-button
                      color="warn">
                      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <button (click)='GoToCheckout()' class="col-sm-12 p-0 checkout" color="warn" mat-raised-button>CHECK
                    OUT <strong *ngIf='mCartCount > 0' class="pl-4" style="font-size: 20px;">{{TotalAmount | number}}<span class="pl-1 Price"
                      [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></strong></button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.Img{
    height: 200px;
    @include desktop{
        height: 250px;
    }
  }

  .Caption{
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
      @include desktop{
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }
}

  .ProductButton{
    background-color: color(messengerBlue);
    color: color(basic);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  
 

  .ProductData{
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: color(gray);
  }
  
  .containerbackground{
    background-color:#f1f3f6;
  }

  .ActiveButton{
    background-color: color(primary);
    color: color(basic);
}

// Change text colour when inputting text
.search {
  //-----Input Field Size----------
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-flex > .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding: 0.4em 0px !important;
    // padding-bottom: 8px !important;
  }
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label-wrapper {
    top: -1.5em;
  }

  ::ng-deep
    .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float
    .mat-form-field-label {
    transform: translateY(-1.1em) scale(0.75);
    width: 133.33333%;
  }
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field {
    background-color: white;
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper {
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper {
      margin: 0 0;
    }
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-start,
    .mat-form-field-outline-end {
      border-radius: 0 !important;
    }
    //   ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    //       height: 0px;
    //   }
    //   ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
    //       padding-top: 0px;
    //       position: relative;
    //   }
    .mat-form-field-underline {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .mat-form-field-ripple {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  }
}


.tree-invisible {
  display: none;
}

.tree ul,
.tree li {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mat-tree-node {
  min-height: 0px;
  max-height: 30px;
  .TreeButton{
    outline: none;
  }
}

.Title{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.banner{
  height: 250px;
}

.ImageDiv{
  width: 40%;
}

.Img{
  height: 130px;
  @include desktop{
      height: 150px;
  }
}

.NameDiv{
    width: 60%;
    .Name{
      width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: lighter;
          font-size: 12px !important;
          white-space: normal;
          word-wrap: break-word;
          color: color(gray);
    }
    .Price{
      width: 100%;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      color: color(primary);
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.imgButton{
  background-color: color(messengerBlue);
  color: color(basic);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btnStyles{
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #f9f9f9);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.cartBtn{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #f9f9f9);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.quantityBox{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 100%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  margin: 0 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center
}


.quantityBox1{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  margin: 0 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center
}

.iconSize {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ItemPromotionPrice {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: color(gray);
}

.ProductPrice{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: color(primary);
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field {
  font-size: 12px; // example
}

.emptycart{
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
}

.YourCartheight{
  min-height: 150px!important;
  max-height:500px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion to use `html:not`
It should be looked like this:

```
html:not([data-scroll='0']) /*class name for category section*/ {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This now works without having to add `data-scroll` via javascript, correct? I'm seeing it working fine without extra javascript on my code but other (maybe older) resources say that there is manual javascript needed for this to work. 

Where can we find more resources on this? Google isn't being super helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the middle container's content scroll, it must first overflow. That can be achieved by applying either a fixed or max height. Then you need to specify the overflow behaviour:

```
.containerbackground {
  background-color:#f1f3f6;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```